# How use 'code template' in 'select templates'

Tags: java, netbeans, snapshot, code-templates

Example:

I enter `n` and press the shortcut `tab`. I get `Object object = new Object ();`. All is well. 'select templates' is first position "Object". I want to use the 'code template' to replace it with "String". I enter `St` and press the shortcut `tab`. Expected result: `String string = new String();` The result: `St st = new St();` + 'select templates' moves to the 2nd position.

I seem to understand why this is happening, but I want to use 'code template' in 'select templates'.

Please tell me who faced this situation and how you solved it.

p.s. perhaps I do not correctly call the term 'select templates'. Please correct me if this is so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I enter  St and press the shortcut tab. Expected result: String string
>   = new String(); The result: St st = new St();

The actual result is the correct behavior because you specified that you want to use the value **St**.

The problem is arising because there are multiple valid possibilities that start with **St** such as **StrictMath** or **String** or **StringBuffer**. NetBeans can't know which of those values you want to use, and by pressing tab you are telling NetBeans that you specifically want to use the value **St**.

Resolve this as follows:

- Enter **St** and then press Control/Space.
- NetBeans will list the available options that start with **St** in a dropdown menu.

[image: controlSpace]

- Scroll down the list, select the entry for **String** and press **Enter**.
- Netbeans will then generate the code you want: **`String string = new String();`**